# ModelForm with Many-to-Many relationship: how to automatically create new entries if needed?

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many

I have two models with a ManyToMany relationship:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)
```

I have this form to update a pizza:

```
class PizzaUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields=('name', 'toppings')
        widgets={'toppings': Select2TagWidget}
```

The `Select2TagWidget` is imported from [django_select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io). I would like to use it to allow *dynamic pizza topping creation* (sounds cool, doesn't it?).

This form is used through this view:

```
def update_pizza(request, pk):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=pizza)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(instance=pizza)
    return render(request, 'pizza/pizza_form.html',
                  {'form': form, 'pizza': pizza})
```

Right now, it works for pre-registered toppings but I would like to allow my users to define new toppings via this same form, which is why I'm using [select2](https://select2.org/tagging) in the first place. Unfortunately, the form doesn't validate if I do so right now, which is to be expected.

If I try to add an *illegal_topping*, here's what happens:

```
"illegal_topping" is not a valid value.
```

I think that I need to iterate over `form['toppings'].value()` in the `if request.method == 'POST'` block before calling form.is_valid() in order to create the new toppings, using `get_or_create` or something similar.

However, if I do that, the values are a mix of existing toppings' IDs and new toppings' names. Everything is a string, so I'm not sure how to evaluate which one are new toppings and which ones were pre-existing.

Maybe would it be great if these values consist only of toppings' names, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Maybe my approach is completely wrong because I'm new to web development and Django in particular, so I would really love to have your input on this. It seems to me that this must be a relatively common problem… but I couldn't find (or understand) help. I know that there must be some M2M problems I'm not anticipating, so any guidance is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty way.

```
class PizzaUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields=('name', 'toppings')
        widgets={'toppings': Select2TagWidget}

    toppings = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Topping.objects.all(),
                                              to_field_name='name',
                                              widget=Select2TagWidget,
                                              required=False)

def update_pizza(request, pk):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=pizza)
        for topping_name in form['toppings'].value():
            topping, created = Topping.objects.get_or_create(name=topping_name)
            if created: topping.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(instance=pizza)
    return render(request, 'pizza/pizza_form.html',
                  {'form': form, 'pizza': pizza})
```

However, I feel like it would be bettre if the topping creation logic wasn't in the view but in the `pizza.forms` module. That'll do for now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are allowing users to either select toppings that already exits or they can create new one, right ? (create_top is name of input filed in which user requests for new topping)

```
def update_pizza(request, pk):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=pizza)
        if form.is_valid():
            ctoppings = []

            form = form.save(commit=False)
            if not request.POST.get['create_top'] = '':
                t, create = Topping.objects.get_or_create(name = request.POST.get['create_top'])
                temp_top = request.POST.getlist('toppings')
                for top in temp_top:
                    ctop = Topping.objects.get(name=top)
                    ctoppings.append(ctop)
                ctoppings.append(t)
                form.toppings.set(ctoppings)
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PizzaUpdateForm(instance=pizza)
    return render(request, 'pizza/pizza_form.html',
                  {'form': form, 'pizza': pizza})
```

see if this can help you.

Comment: This does not work with select2, where I want to fill existing and new toppings with the same widget…